# SSIS ForEach Loop Container - How to dynamically change OLEDB Destination connection at run time

Tags: ssis

There are 4 Connection strings with different SQL Servers (which I set up in SSIS Connection Managers section):
Database name is same in all the servers:
SERVER          DATABASE

1. dbTestServer       dbFees (Main Server and Database)
2. dbTestServer1      dbFees1
3. dbTestServer2      dbFees1
4. dbTestServer3      dbFees1

dbTestServer is the OLEDB Source and other Servers are OLEDB Destination that needs to be updated everytime we run package.
Now, I want to take data from dbTestServer-dbFees and copy to all the other databases. I created a Dataflow task to copy data from dbTestServer to dbTestServer1.

But I need to put this data flow task inside ForEach Loop container to change the connection/Server dynamically so that it will work like:

1. First run- By default OLEDB Source is set to dbTestServer and OLEDB Destination is set to dbServer1 and data is copied from dbFees to dbFees1.
2. Second run-  OLEDB Source is set to dbTestServer and OLEDB Destination is set to dbServer2 and data is copied from dbFees to dbFees1
3. Third run- OLEDB Source is set to dbTestServer and OLEDB Destination is set to dbServer3 and data is copied from dbFees to dbFees1.

I need step by step solution as I am new to SSIS packages and I tried multiple solutions but NOTHING worked so far!

Appreciate your help!

Thank you

Comment: Do the credentials used for server 1,2,3 differ? Are you open to a different approach on this problem?

Comment: You can add a C# script task in your SSIS package.  Then inside the C# script task update/change the connection manager there.  I will have to see if I can find the code I have used to do this but it is possible with C# script task.

Comment: @billinkc: No credentials are same on all the Servers, though I am using Windows Authentication . Please I am open to any approach that will work!

Comment: Brad: Thank you, please let me know if you have code snippet for such dynamic updates.

Comment: Just updated with an answer with my code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `FOR LOOP`.

My logic is to increment variable on each loop and create an expression with a connection string and a number of iteration.

1st step is to create `Connection Manager` with server name **dbTestServer1** and database name **dbFees1**

[image: connection manager]

2nd step will be to add a connection manager to `OLE DB Destination`

[image: OLE DB Destionation]

3rd step is to create 2 variables: **ConnString** and **Iteration**.
For Iteration default value set to 1, because you need dbTestServer **1**
ConnString you need to set like your initial connection string, just on place 1 in dbTestServer1 to set `(DT_STR, 1, 65001)@[User::Iteration]`.

Like on next 2 pictures:

[image: variables]

[image: ConnString expression]

When you set variables, you need to set expression in `OLE DB Connection Manager`.

[image: OLE DB Connection Manager Expression]

From drop-down select `connection string` and type `@[User::ConnString]`.

[image: conn string]

And finally set `FOR LOOP` like on picture

[image: for loop]

**NOTE:** I can't test package because I don't have server names like you, but this is logic of how to solve your problem. And this is only solution for what you asked, you must create whole package on your own.

For main server and database, just add one OLE DB Source with static names for server name and database name.
And you don't need script task if you using my logic.

Comment: Thank you Marko. Can you please tell me code/expression for looping through and picking each server per iteration if server names are dbTestServer_Dev, dbTestServer_SRT and dbTestServer_ET instead of dbTestServer1, dbTestServer2 and dbTestServer3

Comment: I would use nested IF (nested ternary operator). Something like `CASE`.
Create a new variable and set expression like this: `(@[User::Iteration] == 1?"Dev":(@[User::Iteration] == 2?"SRT":(@[User::Iteration] == 3?"ET":"")))`.
After you created a new variable (I named "Server"), add into existing variable connString expression `"Data Source=dbTestServer_" + @[User::Server]  + ";Initial Catalog=dbFees1;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"`.
I hope I was clear.
NOTE: I added `_` into connString expression.

Comment: @smc did you succeed? If you achieved what you try, please accept my answer. Best Regards.

Comment: Sorry @Marko i coudnt respond. i am trying this solution now and will let you know. Appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Marko Ivkovic- I am having issues with setting "OLEDB Destination Connection". Steps I followed till now: 1. Created "OLEDB Source Connection in Connection Manager". 2. Set up Variables: Iteration, ConnString and Server". 3. For Loop with Iteration Expression. 4. Now next step: I created a "Data Flow Task" inside For Loop Container with "OLEDB Source" fixed as dbTestServer. Can you please tell me again how to set up "OLEDB Destination" as it is not working and giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have used to dynamically change connection server/database inside C# Script task in SSIS:

Variables I pass to the C# Script task under ReadOnlyVariables:
(set these up in your Variables inside SSIS)

```
User::DatabaseListOnThisLoop_ConnectionString
User::DatabaseListOnThisLoop_DatabaseName
```

This is the name of the connection string I am dynamically change that is in my ConnectionMangers in SSIS:

```
SourceServerDBForClassification_Dynamic
```

FULL SCRIPT from my C# Script task inside SSIS.  As long as you setup the variables and put the 2 in above in the ReadOnly section of the script task, you should be able to just copy/paste the entire code below into your C# Script task.

NOTE:  The Namespace may give you an issue so may want to keep the one that is generated in your code when adding the script task.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;  // dont think this is needed, I used this for message box for some testing, but leaving here just in case

namespace ST_f8d6dad17af541bbb0010c9fce3ccbb0
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            // get connection string from variable
            
            string ServerConnectionStringOnThisLoop = Dts.Variables["DatabaseListOnThisLoop_ConnectionString"].Value.ToString();
            string DatabaseOnThisLoop = Dts.Variables["DatabaseListOnThisLoop_DatabaseName"].Value.ToString();

            // this could change depend on what type of connection you are using for provider and other settings
            string DynamicConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ServerConnectionStringOnThisLoop + ";Initial Catalog=" + DatabaseOnThisLoop + ";Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            

            // Add the OLE DB connection manager set to existing connection
            ConnectionManager SourceServerDBForClassification_Dynamic = Dts.Connections["SourceServerDBForClassification_Dynamic"];
            

            // now set the dynamic connection above to the connection string passed in from SSIS package
            SourceServerDBForClassification_Dynamic.ConnectionString = DynamicConnectionString;
            

            // now set the package connection to the one we just created from using the variable from the SSIS package
            Dts.Connections["SourceServerDBForClassification_Dynamic"].ConnectionString = SourceServerDBForClassification_Dynamic.ConnectionString;
            
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }


        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };


    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the server and database name in ConnectionManager: SourceServerDBForClassification_Dynamic?

Comment: What should the values be?  That would be the server and DB's you are trying to connect to dynamically from your post above?  For the default ones when you create the connection manager I would go with DEV or TEST as default (but should not matter because the above will change it to what you want at runtime).  If not I am not understanding your question possibly?